# monotonic sequences defined by recurrence relations.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

So I am trying to understand a concept regarding monotonic sequences that are defined by recurrence relations.

Consider two examples :

A.
$$ \ a_{n+1} = \pi + \sqrt{a_{n}-\pi} \ and \ a_{1} > \pi + \sqrt{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ...(1)$$

putting $ a_{n} = a_{n+1} = x \ \ in\ \ (1) \ $ we obtain the polynomial equation \ $ \left ( x-\pi \right )\left ( x-\pi-1 \right ) = 0 \ $ which has two roots $ \ \pi \ and \ \ \pi +1 $

now, $ \ a_{n+1} - a_{n}= -\sqrt{a_{n}-\pi}\left ( \sqrt{a_{n}-\pi}-1 \right ) \ $

so $ a_{1} > \pi + \sqrt{2} => \left \{ a_{n} \right \} $ is decreasing monotonically

thus $ a_{1} > \pi + \sqrt{2} \ \ => a_{1} > \pi + 1 \ \ => \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = \pi + 1 \\$

B.
$$ 7a_{n+1} = a_{n}^{3} + 6 \ and \ a_{1} = \frac{1}{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ...(2) $$

putting $ a_{n} = a_{n+1} = x \ \ in\ \ (2) \ $ we obtain the polynomial equation \ $ \left ( x+3\right )\left ( x-1 \right )\left ( x-2 \right ) = 0 \ $ which has three roots $ \ \ -3, \ \ 1 and \ \ 2 $

now,

$ -3 < a_{1} < 1 \ => \left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ converges to $ -3 \ or \ 1 \ $ depending on if it is monotonic decreasing or increasing respectively

now using $ \  a_{2}-a_{1}=\frac{1}{7}\left ( a_{1}^{3}-7a_{1}+6 \right ) = \frac{1}{7}\left ( \frac{1}{8}-\frac{7}{2}+6 \right )> 0 \ $ we can prove $ \left \{ a_{n} \right \} $ is monotonically increasing

Hence we conclude, $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}=1 $

Now, my questions are :

for a monotonic sequence defined by a recurrence relation $ f\left ( a_{n+1}, a_{n} \right ) = 0 \ $ such that $ f\left ( x, x\right ) $ is a polynomial with all real roots,

1. for any value of $ a_{1} $ is it necessary for the sequence $\left \{ a_{n} \right \} $ to converge ? If yes, then is it necessary for it to converge to a root of $ f\left ( x, x\right ) \ $ ?

2.for any roots $ \alpha \ ,\beta \ $ of $ f\left ( x, x\right ) \ $ if $ a_{1} \epsilon \left [ \alpha ,\beta  \right ] $ then is it necessary for $\left \{ a_{n} \right \} $ to converge to $ \alpha \ or \ \beta \ $ depending on if $\left \{ a_{n} \right \} $ is monotonic decreasing or increasing respectively.

Please explain.

Comment: If $a_{n+1} = a_n + 1$, the sequence never converges...

Comment: If the sequence converges then the limit exists, say $a$. Hence, for sufficiently large $n$, $a_{n+1} = a_n = a$ (approx). Thus the limit turns out to be a root of $f(a,a)$.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy This is not true that for sufficiently larg $n$, $a_{n+1} = a_n = a$. However, if the sequence converges, by continuity of $f$, then the limit is a root of $f$, yes.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe should've mentioned 'approximately'. edited my comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use theorem that every monotonous bounded sequence converge , first, you need to show that sequence is monotone, because otherwise it doesn't have to be true.
You cannot conclude that sequence is monotone by proving for first two element, like you do in your second example. It's necessary to prove that for general $n$.

Answer on your first question is YES when the function $f$ is continuous and sequence $\{a_n\}$ converge, because
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(a_n,a_{n+1})=f(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n,\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1})=0.$$
But if function is not continuous we cannot change order of limit and function.

Your second statement is true if started for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, every $a_n$ is in interval $[\, \alpha,\beta]\,$ and $a_n$ is monotone, but otherwise it don't have to be true.